# In French, plural system treats 0 as "other" instead of "one"

Tags: android, localization, plural

In `res/values/strings.xml`, I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <plurals name="days_amount">
        <item quantity="one">%d day EN</item>
        <item quantity="other">%d days EN</item>
</plurals>
</resources>
```

And in `res/values-fr/strings.xml`, i have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <plurals name="days_amount">
        <item quantity="one">%d jour FR</item>
        <item quantity="other">%d jours FR</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

---

With English locale `res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.days_amount, 0, 0)` returns:

> "0 days"

which is okay per English rules (aka zero quantity <=> several quantities).

---

But with a French locale, it returns:

> "0 jours"

which is NOT okay per French rules (aka zero quantity <=> singular quantity).

It should have returned `"O jour"`

French rules: http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/25/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html#fr

---

So, is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: In my opinion, it's right. Because `0 != 1`. Maybe, you can solve it adding `<item quantity="zero">%d jour FR</item>`?

Comment: If you have a device with English locale and speak Russian, it will write "0 days" (in Russian) instead of "zero days", "no days" (what you wrote in `zero` row). Englishmen don't know about foreign locales and make this mistake in Android. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261290/plural-definition-is-ignored-for-zero-quantity/17261327.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed your concern is right, in French amount 0 should be treated as '`one`' instead of '`other`'. The issue is in some Android APIs: `API <= 16`

So in case you want still to support API 16 just add an extra string key for the zero amount. Let's assume you have:

```
<plurals name="label_message_reminder_text">
        <item quantity="other">Vous avez %1$s nouveaux messages</item>
        <item quantity="one">Vous avez %1$s nouveau message</item>
</plurals>
```

Just add an extra string:

```
<string name="label_message_reminder_text_zero">Vous avez %1$s nouveau message</string>
```

And then when retrieving plurals can do something like:

```
String newMessagesText = getMyString(context, resourceId, amount);
messageTextView.setText(String.format(newMessagesText, amount));
```

And you can have a method to do the getMyString():

```
public String getMyString(Context context, int resourceId, int amount){

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {    
     if(amount == 0) {
        switch (resourceId) {
           case R.plurals.label_message_reminder_text:
              return context.getResources().getString(R.string.label_message_reminder_text_zero);
        }
     }
  }

  return context.getResources().getQuantityString(resourceId, amount);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks correct to me. Here's why:

1. The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals) contains the text `zero, one, two, few, many, and other`, which exactly matches the wording of the [Unicode language plural rules](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/25/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html#fr). This suggests that Android uses them.
2. These plural rules state that the French case of *0 books* is handled by the `one` case.

Since the Android documentation doesn't explicitly mention the Unicode language plural rules, you should request clarification from the Android support.

Before you do that, you should consult [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159556), where the French rules obviously worked.

Answer (score -1):

You're doing something wrong. It's doing exactly what you're telling it to.

Your rules say that when the value is `other`, use "days" or "jours". You then pass in the value 0, which is `other`, so it uses "days" and "jours", as requested.

You could try setting a third value for quantity "zero" which has the language-specific rules.

Comment: Yeah i understand what you both means, but, as i have to discover myself, the plural system doesn't work this way. From the doc: "The selection of which string to use is made solely based on grammatical necessity. In English, a string for zero will be ignored even if the quantity is 0, because 0 isn't grammatically different from 2, or any other number except 1 ("zero books", "one book", "two books", and so on). Conversely, in Korean only the other string will ever be used. " http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals

Comment: Your link states to use `zero` "When the language requires special treatment of the number 0 (as in Arabic)." `Other` should be used "When the language does not require special treatment of the given quantity". In this case, it appears that the value requires special treatment.

Comment: Already tried adding a "zero", it sill chooses the "other" rule. In french, 0 isn't grammatically different from 1, so i expected the system to use the "one" rule when providing 0 as quantity.

Comment: Well, in Spanish, Italian, German and English 0 goes to plural. Strangely enough, in French it's singular. I learned something, today.